# How to run a single doc test in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to only run a particular doc test instead of running all of them. Is there a way I can do this? I know that you can pass `--doc` to run only doc tests but is there a flag that allows me to run just a particular one.

Comment: The best you can do is test a single file at a time. You can also manually disable testing a specific code sample in documentation by adding `ignore` to the code block. Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#attributes

Comment: How would you select this particular test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run doc-tests at the granularity of individual documented items.

If you have some source code like this:

````rust
/// ## Example
/// ```
/// panic!("doctest #1");
/// ```
/// ```
/// panic!("doctest #2");
/// ```
pub fn first() {}

/// ## Example
/// ```
/// panic!("doctest #3");
/// ```
pub fn second() {}
````

Then you can run `cargo test --doc first` to run `doctest #1` and `doctest #2`, and `cargo test --doc second` to run `doctest #3`. Any tests with a path matching the string after `--doc` will be run.